# Sending multidimensional array as key with Laravel http client request

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I want to use the HelloSign API to let users sign contracts through our Laravel application. To make the API calls I use Laravel's Http Client which is build around the Guzzle Http Client.

In order to assign a signer to a HelloSign transaction the API expects the following parameter:

```
signers[Agent][name]
```

Now when I run this in postman. It works like a charm. But when I use the parameters like this in Laravel's HTTP client I receive the following error message: `Invalid parameter: signers[Agent][name]`. But when I use the same exact structure using cURL it workins like a charm.

HTTP Client:

```
Http::withBasicAuth($key, '')->post($url, [
            'test_mode' => '1',
            'template_id' => $template_id,
            'signers[Agent][name]' => 'John Doe',
            'signers[Agent][email_address]' => 'dummy@test.com'
        ]);
```

cURL:

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'test_mode' => '1',
            'template_id' => $template_id,
            'signers[Agent][name]' => 'John Doe',
            'signers[Agent][email_address]' => 'dummy@test.com'
        ),
```

How can I make the HTTP client work?

Comment: Have you tried using a real PHP multi-dimensional array as POST parameter?

Comment: @Mtxz nope.. can you tell me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use multidimensional array:

```
Http::withBasicAuth($key, '')->post($url, [
    'test_mode' => '1',
    'template_id' => $template_id,
    'signers' => [
        'Agent' => [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email_address' => 'dummy@test.com'
        ]
    ]
]);
```